# Sequelize relationship query returns duplicate data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm querying customer orders for a specified customer using Sequelize relationships.

**index.js**

```
var results2 = await customerService.getOrders(1);
console.log(results2);
```

**service.js**

```
exports.getOrders = function (id) {
    return customerModel.findAll({
        raw: true,
        include: [{
            model: orderModel,
            where: { customer_idcustomer: id }
        }],

    }).then(r => r);
};
```

**results**

```
[ { idcustomer: 1,
    customername: 'hello world',
    'orders.idorder': 1,
    'orders.orderdesc': 'order description 1',
    'orders.customer_idcustomer': 1 },
  { idcustomer: 1,
    customername: 'hello world',
    'orders.idorder': 2,
    'orders.orderdesc': 'Test 456',
    'orders.customer_idcustomer': 1 },
  { idcustomer: 1,
    customername: 'hello world',
    'orders.idorder': 3,
    'orders.orderdesc': 'Test 123',
    'orders.customer_idcustomer': 1 } ]
```

**expected**

```
[ { idcustomer: 1,
    customername: 'hello world',
    'orders: [{
       'orders.idorder': 1,
       'orders.orderdesc': 'order description 1',
       'orders.customer_idcustomer': 1 },   
    },
    {
       'orders.idorder': 2,
       'orders.orderdesc': 'order description 2',
       'orders.customer_idcustomer': 1 },   
    },
    {
       'orders.idorder': 3,
       'orders.orderdesc': 'order description 3',
       'orders.customer_idcustomer': 1 },   
    }]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to remove `raw: true,` from query ,

as it will return plain/flat object , and that will convert your object as it looks now.

```
exports.getOrders = function (id) {
    return customerModel.findAll({
        // raw: true, // <------ Just remove this line
        include: [{
            model: orderModel,
            where: { customer_idcustomer: id }
        }],

    }).then(r => r);
};
```

---

> Note : You should put the where condition in upper level as per your
>   logic

```
exports.getOrders = function (id) {
    return customerModel.findAll({
        where: { id: id } ,
        // raw: true, // <------ Just remove this line
        include: [{
            model: orderModel
        }]
    }).then(r => r);
};
```

Comment: I'm getting `metadata` for `customer` and the following for orders `[[Order],[Order]]`

Comment: @rod , that is inside console , if you want to see full response make `JSON.stringify(your_obj)` and `console` that out you will get the idea.

Comment: Ahh, ok...so if this is for an API endpoint I would code it  like   `}).then(r => JSON.stringify(r)); `?

Comment: @rod , no It will return same data as you wanted but it wan't be shown in console, to see that in console only you need to do `JSON.stringify` , getting my point ?

Comment: ok, i think i do now. i tested through web browser and see what you mean. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `raw` key value from your query.

> Finder methods are intended to query data from the database. They do
>   not return plain objects but instead return model instances. Because
>   finder methods return model instances you can call any model instance
>   member on the result as described in the documentation for instances.

If you want to get the data without meta/model information then map your results using

```
{ plain: true }
```

Good sequelize examples in [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)

**Example:**

```
const getPlainData = records => records.map(record =>
  record.get({ plain: true }));

// Your code
return customerModel.findAll({
        // raw: true, <= remove
        include: [{
            model: orderModel,
            where: { customer_idcustomer: id }
        }],

    }).then(getPlainData);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, having

```
raw: true
```

in the options didn't make any difference.

I added

```
distinct: true
```

and the issue disappeared.

I was using `findAndCountAll`, though.

Documentation: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html)