# Sequelize raw query is returning duplicate data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

So, I've got a query that returns some reports made by users, the code is:

```
const reports = await database.query(
  'SELECT r.id, r.type, r.fileCid, r.madeById, r.reportedId, u1.username as reportedName, u2.username as madeBy \
  FROM reports r \
  left join users u1 on u1.id = r.reportedId \
  inner join users u2 on u2.id = r.madeById '
);

return reports;
```

and if I run it on my database directly, it returns this sample data:

```
+----+------+------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+--------------+--------+
| id | type | fileCid | madeById | reportedId | reportedName | madeBy |
+----+------+------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+--------------+--------+
|  5 |    1 | cidF    |        4 |       NULL | NULL         | username    |
|  6 |    0 | cidF    |        4 |       NULL | NULL         | username    |
+----+------+------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+--------------+--------+
```

So my expected result as object would be:

```
[{
        "id": 5,
        "type": 1,
        "fileCid": "cidF",
        "madeById": 4,
        "reportedId": null,
        "reportedName": null,
        "madeBy": "ftk"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "type": 0,
        "fileCid": "cidF",
        "madeById": 4,
        "reportedId": null,
        "reportedName": null,
        "madeBy": "ftk"
    }]
```

but it is indeed returning an array of arrays of this data duplicated:

```
[
    [{
        "id": 5,
        "type": 1,
        "fileCid": "cidF",
        "madeById": 4,
        "reportedId": null,
        "reportedName": null,
        "madeBy": "ftk"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "type": 0,
        "fileCid": "cidF",
        "madeById": 4,
        "reportedId": null,
        "reportedName": null,
        "madeBy": "ftk"
    }],
    [{
        "id": 5,
        "type": 1,
        "fileCid": "cidF",
        "madeById": 4,
        "reportedId": null,
        "reportedName": null,
        "madeBy": "ftk"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "type": 0,
        "fileCid": "cidF",
        "madeById": 4,
        "reportedId": null,
        "reportedName": null,
        "madeBy": "ftk"
    }]
]
```

Why is this happening? it's clearly a problem on sequelize since if I run it directly on MySql is returns only 2 registers as expected... Also, not a duplicated question [from this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51118940/2414842), although it may seems

**Edit**
This is how the report's table is defined. I'm just guessing that because I use two foreign keys to the same table maybe sequelize is making this bug:

```
const Report = database.define('report', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  type: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
  }
},
{
  updatedAt: false
}
)

Report.belongsTo(User, {as: 'madeBy'});
Report.belongsTo(User, {as: 'reported'});
Report.belongsTo(File);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code you've pasted above is the same code that is running? Try changing something in the query, like removing a column from the SELECT list.

Comment: yes, it is the same code. I'm using `nodemon` on dev. I also made the test you recommend and the error persists.

Comment: What happens if you add `{ type: QueryTypes.SELECT }` as a second argument in `.query` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` function can accept option as second argument and this `type` option will determine how the response is formatted.

```
// The type of query you are executing. The query type affects how results are formatted before they are passed back.
type: QueryTypes.SELECT
```

More option for raw query: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

Your query is SELECT, so adding the type SELECT will format response as regular Sequelize `findAll`.

```
const reports = await database.query(
    'SELECT r.id, r.type, r.fileCid, r.madeById, r.reportedId, u1.username as reportedName, u2.username as madeBy \
    FROM reports r \
    left join users u1 on u1.id = r.reportedId \
    inner join users u2 on u2.id = r.madeById ',
{ type: QueryTypes.SELECT }
);
```

Also, alternatively you could change this raw query to `findAll` which is more Sequelize way.